# regular expression - find - replace

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

In my project I have sometime written

```
= {:key=>"value", :key2=>value2}
```

I need to replace with space between key value arrow like below:

```
= {:key => "value", :key2 => value2}
```

I could find it by `[^\s-]=>[^\s-]` but , I don't know how to replace such a way it should be like

`= {:key => "value", :key2 => value2}`

Comment: check out the cane gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

FIND :  `([^\s-])=>([^\s-])`

REPLACE : `$1 => $2`

It worked for me...

Cheers!!!
Hurrrreh!!!

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer, so the question will be marked as resolved.

Comment: Thanks fardjad !It is resolved :).